# Cannot Reset MySQL password

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I have been stuck on this for a long time, I tried to follow the instructions located here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html. When I run the commands I get this as my output:

```
2021-01-01T09:15:04.445377Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 19920
2021-01-01T09:15:04.487135Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-01T09:15:04.901676Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-01T09:15:05.135403Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2021-01-01T09:15:05.240496Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-01T09:15:05.242979Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-01T09:15:05.325105Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-01-01T09:15:45.594^C297Z 0 [System] [MY
-013105] [Server] C:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>\Pro
gram Files\MySQL\MC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>ySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2021-01-01T09:15:46.281364Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysqld --init-file=C:\Users\user\text.txt --console
2021-01-01T09:15:51.297226Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 21652
2021-01-01T09:15:51.320019Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-01T09:15:51.784233Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-01T09:15:52.015722Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2021-01-01T09:15:52.118175Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-01T09:15:52.126894Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-01T09:15:52.205977Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I am not sure what to do from here because I do not think it is on the tutorial. Any help solving this would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Because no errors are shown (But this `2021-01-01T09:15:45.594^C297` does not look OK!), you should proceed with the next step as shown in the [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), and do a check if your password is changed.  If your password is not changed, please create a simple init-file (i.e. the same as is suggested in step 3), and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no errors are shown (But this 2021-01-01T09:15:45.594^C297 does not look OK!), you should proceed with the next step as shown in the procedure.

Do a check if your password is changed.

If your password is not changed, please create a simple init-file (i.e. the same as is suggested in step 3), and try again.

If your password is changed, then do not forget to delete the `init-file`.

### EDIT

:  I did a reset of my 'root' password following the [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

All output of this session is here, with some NOTE's in between:

First we notice that we do not know the password:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *******
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>
```

Then a mysql-init.txt file is created:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>type mysql-init.txt
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Then we stop the MySQL server. My server is name MySQL80, but you can also stop it from the services window (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885038/stop-mysql-service-windows))

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>net stop MySQL80
The MySQL80 service is stopping.
The MySQL80 service was stopped successfully.
```

Password reset with:

- Note the double \\ in the path names, and the " surrounding the complete path
- My default settings for MySQL are located here "D:\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini", this is almost sure different at your location

```
    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="D:\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --init-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\mysql-init.txt" --console
    2021-01-01T18:51:09.333120Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
    2021-01-01T18:51:09.333840Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 21888
    2021-01-01T18:51:09.341869Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    2021-01-01T18:51:09.908748Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    2021-01-01T18:51:10.083573Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
    2021-01-01T18:51:10.143779Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    2021-01-01T18:51:10.144078Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
    2021-01-01T18:51:10.192745Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Now the server is started with output to console, to stop the server type CTRL+C:

```
2021-01-01T18:51:20.697066Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
^C
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>2021-01-01T18:51:21.447960Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

We start the server again, the normal way (or via services):

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>net start mysql80
The MySQL80 service is starting.
The MySQL80 service was started successfully.
```

And we try to logon:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>mysql -u root -pMyNewPass
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.22 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> alter user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'stackoverflow';
```

With this last command the password can be changed to 'stackoverflow'. I am sure any who read this can think of a better password.

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said but everytime I run `mysql -u root -p` and enter a password  I get
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you followed the steps, you should be able to log on with the password `MyNewPass`. Maybe provide the command you used (they are in the procedure) but clearly something is done different then is explained there.... (BTW: after the password reset, you could also do `mysql -u root -pMyNewPass` (no space between `-p` and the password))

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening that's different from the instructions, I get the error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying.

Comment: I added the procedure step by step, and did not find any errors in it, so maybe the notes will be of help.